# Code syntax handling and checker tool for IOS developement

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have been working over a project of Native IOS. I am using xcode with cocoa touch.So can you suggest me which Is the best open source tool available for code syntax handling and checking.Like having check for indentation, extra line spaces in the code and all.

One more thing if somebody can suggest me that what is best tool for code covrage for unit test cases in ios app development.

Comment: There's an open source plugin for Xcode: https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode

Comment: Actually i used that one, but can i define my own indentation styles and other rules like braces should be must after if in that.

Comment: Yes you can (at least indentation I know for sure, braces shouldn't be a problem either). Just add a configuration file (.clang-format) to your project (or anywhere near it in your directory structure (it will use the one that's nearest to your project). You can create a custom style by specifying your attributes in the .clang-format ([full list](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html))